# unable to plot dates on x axis in df.plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am facing conversion error.

`df1.plot(x='Date', y=['predictions','withdrawals_sum'],xticks=df.Date, rot=90)`

```
error:
ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units:

0      2019-11-11
1      2019-11-18
2      2019-11-25
3      2019-12-02
4      2019-12-09
5      2019-12-16
6      2019-12-23
7      2019-12-30
8      2019-11-11
9      2019-11-29
10     2019-12-17
11     2019-11-28
12     2019-12-03
Name: Date, Length: 281, dtype: object
```

Comment: Well it looks like your date column is not actually of datetime type.

Comment: How working if omit `xticks=df.Date` ? Also first convert column to datetimes by `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)`

Comment: Index                         object
ATM_ID                         int64
Date                  datetime64[ns]
Cash for _ days                int64
Replenishment_Act            float64
Withdrawals                  float64
Suggested                     object
Suggested_Filled              object
Balance                      float64
Correct_Balance                int64
Deviation                     object
withdrawals_sum                int64
Correct Deviations            object
predictions                    int64

Comment: You might be able to go through the dates, and cast them to datetime type. You may need to cast them to a string first.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the Date variable into a datetime object using `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)`